# send email to task assignee using powershell?

Tags: powershell, email, task-list

I want to send daily reminders to users who have tasks assigned to them. It seems like a simple way to do this would be to write a Powershell script that sends an email for each item, and set up a scheduled task to run the script once a day. However, the script  below returns something like `1;#John Doe` (full name) for each item.

Is there a way to get the user's email address, or Windows username, from the task list item using Powershell? I think there must be, since SharePoint is able to send mail to the assignee when the task is created.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysharepointsite
$list = $web.Lists["Task List Test"]    
foreach ($item in $list.items)
{
    if ($item["Status"] -ne "Completed")
    {     
        write-host $item["Assigned To"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Script returns lookup value. So you can parse the num part of that string - user ID and then find it by command

```
$web.Users.GetById($parsedId)
```

whole script:

```
$value = "1;#user name";

$arr = $value.Split(";#");
$parsedId = $arr[0];
$user = $web.Users.GetById($parsedId);

write-host "mail:" $user.Email
```

Comment: That script has a couple of problems: 1) `$arr[0]` returns the part before the delimiter. Should be `$arr[2]`. 2) Once fixed, it returns John Doe, AKA full name, not username. Do you know of a way to get the username?

Comment: Script returns user ID ($arr[0]) and then you query for $user by ID. If you want login name, just type $user.LoginName;

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for me `$arr[0]` returns `1`.

Comment: And that is supposed to be user id. Lookup column consists of ID;#display name

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm getting an error with Users.GetById. If I can resolve that, I'll mark this as the anwer. ---- Exception calling "GetByID" with "1" argument(s): "U
At C:\powershell\taskListEmail2.ps1:22 char:28
+ $user = $web2.Users.GetById <<<< ($parsedId)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: method name is with lowercase "d" GetById. Also you can use this statement: $web.Users | ?{ $_.ID -eq $id }